Method inheritance in GML
So, I have a "trigger" system in a mod for a Pizza Tower, i made so that there is a obj_trigger parent and an obj_delay child, the parent has a method to execute the main functionality of a trigger.
obj_trigger Create
trigger_id = -1;
target_trigger_id = -1;

on_enter = 1;
on_touch = 0;
on_trigger = 0;

multi = 0;
activated = 0;

execute = function(triggered) //gml_Script_anon_gml_Object_obj_trigger_Create_0_0_gml_Object_obj_trigger_Create_0
{
    var triggered = argument0;
}

obj_trigger Room Start
if (on_enter && (!activated))
{
    execute(false)
    if (!multi)
        activated = 1;
}

obj_delay Create
event_inherited()
delay = 1
execute = function(argument0) //gml_Script_anon_gml_Object_obj_delay_Create_0_0_gml_Object_obj_delay_Create_0
{
    var triggered = argument0
    if (triggered && (!on_trigger))
        return;
    if (triggered && activated)
        return;
    if (triggered && (!multi))
        activated = 1
    if ((delay == 0))
        alarm[0] = 1
    else
        alarm[0] = (delay * room_speed)
}

The problem here is that I'm trying to overwrite gml_Script_anon_gml_Object_obj_trigger_Create_0_0_gml_Object_obj_trigger_Create_0 with the new method but it instead turns into gml_Script_anon_gml_Object_obj_delay_Create_0_0_gml_Object_obj_delay_Create_0
I am using UndertaleModTool so I don't know if that has something to do with it.

The way to fix it is:
Always prefix your methods with self.
For example to avoid the function buffer thing from creating a non-existing function in any other files you can do for example:
self.execute()
This way you can do execute = function() {things here} on the child and the parent script will execute the new function definition!
Also, this is using UTMT:CE and if you put self. and it removes it is because it is not necessary if it keeps it, it matters.
I made this conclusion by a bit of testing so everything might not be true.

In GameMaker, function literals are "flattened" during compilation, so
greet = function(name) {
    return "hi, " + name + "!";
}

becomes something akin to
greet = method(self, gml_Script_anon_1);

with gml_Script_anon_1 containing
return "hi, " + argument0 + "!";

If you are trying to overwrite a method inside an event, you might be able to locate it separately in the Scripts list, though this depends on UTMT implementation.

I think that'll work, So should I also use method_call?

It didn't work it just said that the methods I defined werent defined so if you don't know any other I'll maybe use a clunky but working alarm system, maybe the errors are because of UTMT at this point Idk.

I think it may be cuz the function registry or something like that, I've heard it a curses data.win if somehow you make UTMT think it is a function without using the gml_Script_anon thing.

If you cannot add a new function literal, you could add a regular script and bind it to instance using method (or not bind it to instance and use script_execute to run it)

This could work but I found mt current answer way better and easier to understand, also you could have not understood the question.

some() should already compile to self.some() when there is no function/script called some, but that might be a problem with UTMT - see if that is easily reproduced and file a bug if so.
